# How to sum n to x in java class?

Tags: java, calculator

I am writing a java class that functions as a calculator.

I want to write a program that returns the sum of num1 to num2 when the user selects @ and enters values.

For example, if you enter 1 and 100, the code should return 5050 as a result.

Should I use loops?
I recently started learning the java language. So I can't be confident about the grammar.

Thank you for your help.

Below is a snippet of the calculator code.

```
public int calc(int num1, int num2, String op) {
    int result = 0;

    if(op.equals("+")) {
        result = num1 + num2;
    }

    else if(op.equals("@")) {
        //I need help with this part.

    }

    return result;
    
}
```

Comment: "sum of num1 to num2" - you mean you want to _iterate_ from `num1` to `num2` and sum up all values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use loops?

Sure. If you want.

Note that there is a mathematical formula for this. Consider summing the numbers from 1 to 10.

You could just go: `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10`. In other words, `int sum = 0; for (int i = lowest; i <= highest; i++) sum += i;`.

or, you realize that you could also rewrite that: Pair the highest and lowest number: `1+10 + 2+9 + 3+8 + 4+7 + 5+6`. And then, realise that you always end up with a sequence of pairs that are all the same sum: That is `11 + 11 + 11 + 11 + 11`. And there will be 'length/2' such pairs. In other words, for an 'even' amount of sequential numbers, it's `(highest + lowest) * ((1+highest-lowest)/2`. For an 'odd' amount of sequential numbers, it's the same, except you then add the middle number in the end.

If the point was to learn about math, try to program the above. If it's to learn about loops, hey, a for loop might be slower, but it's a computer. It can loop through a few million numbers and add em up considerably faster than the blink of an eye. Either one will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for answer!
This is just an exercise. I just wanted to get a definite answer.

Comment: Just curious, where and when did the OP mentioned _applets_?

Comment: I'd swear it said 'applets' before. In any case, it doesn't right now, so I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(op.equals("@")) {
    if (num1 < num2) {
        while (num1 <= num2) {
            result += num1++;
        }
    } else if (num1 > num2) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: num1 must be less than num2");
    } else {
        reusult = num1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it was helpful.

Comment: This code could be helpful, but assumes that num1 is always less than num2. It will work indefinitely if you just throw an if statement in there to swap the 2 numbers.

`else if(op.equals("@")) {
    //swap the numbers if num2 is smaller
    if (num1 > num2){
        int temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }
    while (num1 <= num2){
          result += num1;
          num1++;
    }
}`

Comment: @cMcNerlin I changed it a bit, so it include every case

Comment: Under what circumstances would the 'else' branch be taken?

Comment: when num1 is equal to num2.
Oh,  now im not sure if this is right. Maybe when num1 is equal to num2, the result is num1

Comment: Yes, I think n@n should just return n. Follow the pattern 5@7=5+6+7, 5@6=5+6, 5@5=5.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I'm gonna change this, too.